# Como somar dois valores de uma input marcando checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu estou querendo saber como faço pra somar dois valores que são setados quando marco a checkbox.

eu eu fiz esse código,Ele não funciona como eu esperava,eu queria que ele pegasse o número que já está no input e somar com outro valor quando marcar a checkbox,e remover a mesma quantia que foi adicionada quando desmarcar.

```js
$('#booster15p').change(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked')){
          
          $('#tdmxp').val(10+1.5);
        
          
     }else{
         
          $('#tdmxp').val(11.5-1.5);
          
     } 
});


$('#booster50p').change(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked')){
          
          $('#tdmxp').val(10+5);
          
          
     }else{
         
          $('#tdmxp').val(15-5);
     
     }
    
    
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="1.5" id="booster15p"/>Aumenta em 1.5
<input type="checkbox" name="5" id="booster50p"/>Aumenta em 5

<input class="tdmxp" id="tdmxp" value="10" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada uma das funções de `change` altera o valor final de `#tdmxp` apenas com base no seu `checked` e partindo do valor `10`, logo nunca poderá ter a soma dos dois, nem funciona para outro valor que esteja no `<input>` que não seja `10`.

No caso é mais simples combinar ambas as funções numa só considerando individualmente cada `checked` e um valor base do `input`.

Exemplo:

```js
let valorBase = parseFloat($("#tdmxp").val()); //valor base inicial

$('#booster15p, #booster50p').change(function(){ 
//    ^------------^ mesmo evento change para os dois checkboxes
  let valorFinal = valorBase; //começa no base
  if ($("#booster15p").is(":checked")){ //se o 1.5 ta marcado acrescenta 1.5
    valorFinal += 1.5;
  }
  if ($("#booster50p").is(":checked")){ //se o 5 ta marcado acrescenta 5
    valorFinal += 5;
  }

  $("#tdmxp").val(valorFinal); //coloca o valor final no input
});

$("#tdmxp").change(function(){
  //se o usuario mudar o input, altera o valor base
  valorBase = parseFloat($("#tdmxp").val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="1.5" id="booster15p"/>Aumenta em 1.5
<input type="checkbox" name="5" id="booster50p"/>Aumenta em 5

<input class="tdmxp" id="tdmxp" value="10" >
```

Da forma que ficou no exemplo mesmo se o usuário alterar o valor da caixa os incrementos irão funcionar corretamente pois o valor base para as somas é alterado.

Utilizando ternários dá para compactar bastante o código, mantendo a mesma ideia:

```js
let valorBase = parseFloat($("#tdmxp").val()); 
$('#booster15p, #booster50p').change(function(){ 
  $("#tdmxp").val(valorBase + ($("#booster15p").is(":checked") ? 1.5: 0) + 
    ($("#booster50p").is(":checked") ? 5: 0) );
});

$("#tdmxp").change(function(){
  valorBase = parseFloat($("#tdmxp").val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="1.5" id="booster15p"/>Aumenta em 1.5
<input type="checkbox" name="5" id="booster50p"/>Aumenta em 5
<input class="tdmxp" id="tdmxp" value="10" >
```

Answer (score 6):

Bom, você só precisa buscar o valor do seu elemento e depois somar/subtrair com o que você deseja. Não se esqueça de transformar o valor em um float, pois os valores dos elementos do DOM sempre vem como strings.

```
let tdmxp = $('#tdmxp');
let valorAtual = parseFloat(tdmxp.val());
tdmxp.val(valorAtual + 1.5);
```

Ou então você pode passar um callback para o método val

```
$('#tdmxp').val((i, v) => parseFloat(v) + 1.5);
```

Comment: Obrigado,funcionou muito bem.usei o método 1 q é muito mais fácil de entender kkk muito obrigado mesmo